# Select output device with MPMusicPlayerController

Tags: ios, bluetooth, swift3, mpmusicplayercontroller, mpmediapickercontroller

I have an app where you can choose from your itunes library which songs you want to play (MPMediaPickerController and MPMusicPlayerController). That works without any problem. 
Is there a way to show and select the output devices (iphone or connected bluetooth speaker)?

Comment: `MPVolumeView` with `showsRouteButton` to `YES` ?

Comment: Great! Thanks very much!

Comment: Hey @Patricks. Is there any need to ask for Music Permission while fetching track details from MPMusicPlayerController (Swift3 - iOS 10) ?

Comment: I have set the 'Privacy - Media Library Usage Description' key in the info.plist to 'This app wants to use your music library'